# not able to inject service which has $http dependancy into $httpProvider even with $injector giving circular dependancy error

Tags: angularjs

factory which I want to inject into `$httpprovider` interceptors:

```
$provide.factory('verifyUser',['$q','$injector',function($q,$injector){

    return {
        getStatus:function(){
            var $http=$injector.get('$http');
            var defer=$q.defer();
            var config={
                    headers:{
                        "Accept": "application/json",
                        'Content-Type':undefined,
                        "no-intercept":true
                    }
                };

            var url="rest/checkLoginStatus";
            $http.get(url,config).then(function(response){
                console.log(" /checkLoginStatus val"+response.data);
                defer.resolve(response.data);
            },
            function(response){
                console.log("failed");
            });
            return defer.promise;
        }
        };
}]);
```

and my `$httpProvider` interceptor function is :

```
var httpInterceptorFunc=['$q','$location','$injector',function($q,$location,$injector){

            var verifyUser=$injector.get('verifyUser');
            return {
                request:function(config){
                    config.headers['pragma']='no-cache';
                    config.headers['Cache-Control']='no-cache';
                    var isUserLoggedIn= false;

                    verifyUser.getStatus().then(function(data){
                        isUserLoggedIn=data;
                    });
                    var request= isUserLoggedIn ? config :null;
                    $('#spinner').show();
                    $('#spinnerBlur').show();
                    return request;
                },
                response:function(response){
                    $('#spinner').hide();
                    $('#spinnerBlur').hide();
                    return response;
                },
                responseError:function(errorResponse){
                    var errorCode=errorResponse.status;
                    $('#spinner').hide();
                    $('#spinnerBlur').hide();
                    if(errorCode==403){
                        window.location='/403error';
                    }
                    console.log("----------response error-----------");
                    return $q.reject(errorResponse);
                },requestError:function(errorRequest){              //use??
                    $('#spinner').hide();
                    $('#spinnerBlur').hide();
                    console.log("----------request error-----------");
                    return $q.reject(errorRequest);
                }

            };
        }];

        $provide.factory('httpInterceptor',httpInterceptorFunc);
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
```

I tried using $injector too..but my code is looping infinitely.. 
Plz help .. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you set the `no-intercept` header to `true` and then not use it?

Comment: Be aware that the AngularJS framework uses the $http service to load directive templateURLs and router templateURLs. An interceptor that asks a server for login status on every XHR is not a good idea.

Comment: Thnq for the response.Plz ignore "no-intercept" header,i was trying some otherthing to avoid intercepting that factory from second time but i did not use it though.